# Dreamweaver showing boxes instead of unicode characters

Tags: php, unicode, dreamweaver

My pages when viewed in browser are working fine. I have a language file (in .php extension), but without any HTML tags. I m using Dreamweaver CS5.5 to edit these files.

I have a variable `$lang["label_name"]`, which holds the value. in dreamweaver code view, all the devnagari unicode character appears as boxes. But in another machine, with same version of dreamweaver, when same file is opened, the unicode characters are showing correctly.

Is there any settings that I missed in my machine? How to make unicode character appear correctly in Dreamweaver (not talking about browser)?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder why my question is down voted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any settings that I missed in my machine?

Probably. Just compare the setup between the two dreamweaver installations and add the differences to your question. This might then be easier to say.

> How to make unicode character appear correctly in Dreamweaver (not talking about browser)?

By configuring it properly. Also ensure that you are using the same font on both systems and the files have the same encoding and Dreamweaver is aware of the correct encoding.